# Why is graphics not showing on my JFrame / JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, java-7

When I run this code. The result is a window with the name. Fully blank. I tried editing background color and adding graphics (rectangle) etc but the same result keeps occurring .

Question: This ends up as a white screen on a window. No graphics or background color. Even though I added it to panel and added panel. How do I fix this?

**Main.java**

```
package ball.tec.main;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import ball.tec.frame.Frame;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String Version = "0.1.2";
        Frame f = new Frame();
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.add();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setSize(1500, 1000);
        f.setTitle("RedBall V: " + Version);
    }
}
```

**Frame.java**

```
    package ball.tec.frame;

    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    public class Frame extends JFrame{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public boolean debug = false;

        //Creating panel object
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        //Graphics displayed
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        //Firstly Nothing pops up
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawRect(20, 40, 10, 10);

        //And this doesn't work.
        this.setBackground(Color.RED);
    }

    //Add everything to 'panel'
    public void add() {
    add(panel);

    //Even if I put it here it doesn't work ;-;
    this.setBackground(Color.RED);
    this.pack();
 }
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you be changing the background color of the JPanel instead?

Comment: Thanks if you can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use `paintComponent()` in a `JFrame`.  What you probably intended to do was create a third class, extending `JPanel`.  Add your `paintComponent()` there.

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawRect(20, 40, 10, 10);
        this.setBackground(Color.RED);
    }
}

f.add(new MyPanel());
```

Comment: Thanks! Im not getting confused now.

Comment: And also, the `setBackground(Color.RED)` call can be moved in the constructor. No need to set the background everytime the `paintComponent` is called.

Comment: Also it works but you made a mistake your dont do f.add it doesnt work it has to be add() just saying

Comment: Wait nows it red and the graphics are not showing is this becuase the background is overlapping the graphics?

Comment: @elliot5 It's because before drawing the rectangle, you are setting the graphics color to red, which is the same as the background color. Change it to some other color and you will see the rectangle.

Comment: Thanks! I know logic of java now im moving to swing and graphics its a hard change. Thanks for the support!